# Replace white spaces only at the beginning and end of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

Does anyone know how to replace white spaces in the beginning and end of the string with &nbsp using regular expression and javascript;

Example:

```
`   Hello World. The white spaces in between the sentence should not be replaced. Only the start and end should be replaced with &nbsp.   `
```

After replacing:

```
`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello World. The white spaces in between the sentence should not be replaced. Only the start and end should be replaced with &nbsp.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first capture the `space` and than in callback function of replace you can add the no. of `&nbsp;` based on length of match.

- `^\s+` - Matches spaces at the start of string.
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR.
- `\s+$` - Matches spaces at the end of string

```js
let str = `   Hello World. The white spaces in between the sentence should not be replaced. Only the start and end should be replaced with &nbsp.   `

let op = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, function(match){
  return `&nbsp;`.repeat(match.length)
})

console.log(op)
```